# Is there quickstart archetype for jboss fuse using spring di

Tags: spring, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fabric8

Since blueprint seems to be a pain in the ass (as a dependency injection framework) we want use Spring DI (Java based) for future service implementaions (Camel based). At the moment we deploy all services on a fuse 6.3 in fabric mode.

[Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Developing_and_Deploying_Applications-en-US.pdf](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Developing_and_Deploying_Applications-en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Developing_and_Deploying_Applications-en-US.pdf) states:

> A typical Red Hat JBoss Fuse application is based on a specific development model, which is based
>   around the Java language, Spring or blueprint dependency injection frameworks...

Is there a good maven archetype to start with? I found those [fabric8 archetypes](https://fabric8.io/guide/quickstarts/archetypes.html) but they seem to target fabric8 v2 - a complete different world, isn't it?

Comment: I suggest to use and ask Red Hat customer portal - you can also search their knowledge based etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use camel-archetype-spring archetype with org.apache.camel.archetypes group.

example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=camel-spring-app -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-spring -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Comment: thanks i started with this one, but it didn't helped much with the osgi part. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

In meantime i found

https://github.com/FuseByExample/

this examples helped much. the most tricky part is the configuration of bundle plugin and fabric8.